# What FFMPEG return when camera is disabled (unplug)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, camera, rtsp

I use FFMPEG to connect to a IP camera via RTSP stream. I try to detect if connection is lost. I create timeout with interrupt_callback, and check the output of av_read_frame(), sometime it work and can reconnect to camera. But if I disable the camera (unplug the network cable), it's blocked and pause forever.
Hope someone has similar issue and can help me.
Here what I try:

Setting for interrupt_callback:

```
ifmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
ifmt_ctx->interrupt_callback.callback = interruptCallback;
ifmt_ctx->interrupt_callback.opaque = this;

if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_file, 0, &options)) != 0) {
    log.error("Could not open input stream {}", in_file);
    return 1;
}
```

interrupt_callback function:

```
int CtFfmpeg::interruptCallback(void *ctx)
{
    CtFfmpeg* camera = reinterpret_cast<CtFfmpeg*>(ctx);
    struct tm *tm;
    time_t now;
    now = time(0);
    tm = localtime (&now);
    int nowTime_callback = tm->tm_sec;
    if ((nowTime_callback - camera->initTime_callback) > 15) { //Timeout after 20 seconds
        Logger log{__func__};
        log.error("Time out");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Try to restart connection:

```
ff->ret = av_read_frame(ff->ifmt_ctx, &(ff->tmp_pkt));

    if (ff->ret < 0){
    // do restart here
}
```

Comment: You ever figure this one out?